Is $\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^m(x)dx=-\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\cos^m(x)dx$ correct?
Here is part of an answer from this MSE post,

Let $m$ odd,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^m(x)dx=-\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\cos^m(x)dx$$
$$\int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}\cos^m(x)dx=-\int_{3\pi/2}^{2\pi}\cos^m(x)dx$$

I wonder if these equations are correct. For example, for $\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\cos^m(x)dx$, I got this expression:
$$\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\cos^m(x)dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^m(x+\pi/2)dx=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^mxdx$$
I used $\cos(x+\pi/2)=-\sin x$.

Use instead $\cos(x+\pi)=-\cos(x)$ and $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$. Then the first formula can be found as:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^m x dx=\int_{-\pi/2}^0\cos^m x dx=\int_{\pi/2}^\pi(-1)^m\cos^m x dx$$
The first step is change $x$ to $-x$, the second is $x$ to $x+\pi$.
You can use a similar approach for the second equation.
